# Display table when ng-click based on the id

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

I have the following angular script, its does nothing but create a list of objects:

```
//To get the existing records
$scope.get_records = function(){
  filter_data = {set__iexact: $scope.final_data.set};
  bin.get(filter_data,
        function(data){
        $scope.main_list = data['objects'];
        console.log($scope.main_list);
        angular.forEach($scope.main_list, function(f) {

        });
    },function(data, status){
            console.log('Stage1: Internal error while loading initial data:'+status );
        }
)};
```

The unique field in each record is the id. And I am displaying these ids as a table (tr) in HTML.

```
<table class="table table paleblue table-fixed">
    {%verbatim %}
    <tr align="center" ng-repeat="f in main_list" ng-cloak>
        <td><button class="btn btn-small">{{f.id}}</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to show a table below the current `td`, which only contains the elements of that particular id. How can I do that? How to get that specific id so that I can filter it together with the `set`? Any idea?

Comment: *"how do I get the id"* ... are you saying `f.id` isn't correct? question/problem statement is not very clear

Comment: f.id is correct. But I need get the objects of that particular id and display in a table. :)

Comment: And the problem doing that is what specifically?

Comment: how can I get the table of that specific id? How to pass that id to get the data

Comment: `ng-click="controllerFunction(f)"`

Comment: yeah. That worked. Thanks Charlietfi

Answer (score 0):

You must add:

0 - The Filter: A second row will have the ID of other elements to filter, in my case will be father row.

```
<tr align="center" ng-repeat="f in main_list" ng-cloak>
```

Will change to

```
<tr align="center" ng-repeat="f in main_list |  filter:{father:selected}" ng-cloak>
```

1 - Set the Filter: When click the `Id set the filter with the id value, in my case I click a custom link, and set the Id as`$scope.selected` to filter by this element in other row: Father Row.

```
<td><button class="btn btn-small">{{f.id}}</button></td>
```

Will change to

```
<td><a ng-click="$parent.selected=element.id">Show sons of {{element.id}}</a></td>
```

As you can see I use `$parent.selected`. Because when you are in an ng-repeat you are in a SUB SCOPE of your CONTROLLER SCOPE.

Check the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vtsOsBFzDPXEPg3QW5yn?p=preview